# How to import old mails from older Thunderbird to latest version

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

My PC crashed a few days ago so now I'm installing a new one. After setting up the latest version of Thunderbird, I wanted to import the old mails I still had from a backup.

As I see it, my old drive contains a folder with a lot of files without extention and the same files with the .msf extention, as well as some folders with an sbd added to the name.

Online, I found an article discussing ImportExportTools which I tried, but after importing any of the above directories, the only thing that happens is that an empty folder is added to my profile without any mails.

I've also tried to simply copy one of the files (the file with and without extention) to my new mail directory. When I started Thunderbird, it briefly appeared, but disappeared after Thunderbird was finished starting.

So I'm left with two questions:

1. Why doesn't ImportExportTools import the mails correctly?
2. If ImportExportTools fails, how can I import or access these mails and add them to my new profile?

My old PC was running Windows 7, can't remember the Thunderbird version, the new one is running Windows 10 with Thunderbird 68.10.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thunderbird on GNU/Linux (Ubuntu)

`/home/$USER/.thunderbird/` contains a folder named e.g. `0wb9bh5h.default` (look for *.default) this holds the main settings AND all your locally stored email.

I have several times (most recently in April) reinstalled Thunderbird, with all old mail reappearing, by:

1. Install Thunderbird
2. Run T. and set up at least ONE email account
3. Quit T.
4. Peek in the $HOME/.thunderbird folder;
5. rename the *.default folder
6. COPY your old *.default in its place (do *not* rename!)
7. Restart T. and check; usually it picks up the changed folder.
8. Check all settings; they should be OK.

**NEW, if the above is not enough:**
Just checked: In `/home/$USER/.thunderbird/` there are a pair of *.ini files that has content pinpointing the *.default dir.

*I suggest:*
Stop T, rename these files for backup, create copies where you change the name to the name of YOUR dir. Restart T.

Comment: thank you very much, this worked like a charm!